# Adding eventhandler to tab context menu throws null pointer exception

Tags: javafx, tabs, event-handling, addeventlistener

I would like to add the event handler to a tab context menu. And after the tab context menu is selected I would like to remove the event handler from the node. The problem is that `Tab2.getContextMenu().addEventHandler(Event.ANY,handler);` throws a `NullPointerException`.

`@FXML Tab Tab2;` - Tab2 can be found in my fxml with fx:id="Tab2"

```
EventHandler<Event> handler = (new EventHandler<Event>() {
            public void handle(Event event) {
                System.out.println("Tab2 is selected!");
                Tab2.getContextMenu().removeEventHandler(Event.ANY, this);
            }
});
Tab2.getContextMenu().addEventHandler(Event.ANY, handler);
```

The code takes place in `initialize` function.

I would like to achive a similar solution like this:

```
    Tab2.setOnSelectionChanged(e -> {
        if(Tab2.isSelected()) {
            System.out.println("Tab2 is selected!");
        }
    });
```

Unfortunately, with this solution it will run all the time on selection. But I want it to happen only once and also remove the event listener.

This asker used a similar solution like me:
[How to remove an event handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41025800/how-to-remove-an-event-handler)

But he had no problem with adding the event handler.

**EDIT:**

It seems like getContextMenu() function causes the nullpointer exception and it also seems I kind of misunderstood what that function does. I wanted to get the tab's "header".

But the question remains the same. How can I add an event listener to a tab, and after it is selected the first time remove the event listener from it. That's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the listener value as null

e.g.:

```
tab1.setOnSelectionChanged((e)->{
    if(tab1.isSelected()){
        tab1.setOnSelectionChanged(null);
    }
});
```

Comment: Will it cause the event listener to cease permanently, like it is removed?

Comment: @Ricky Yes, calling `setOnXXX(null)` will remove the previous handler.

Comment: It solved my problem. Thank you Slaw and Josev. The solution turned out to be pretty easy and useful as well.